# Return a structured row in Dask apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I am applying a function on all the rows in a **Dask dataframe**. In `PySpark` I'm able to return a `spark.sql.Row` object with named parameters in order to create a structured row for the resulting `DataFrame`. How do I return a similarly structured row (with columns and types) when applying a function on the rows in a dask dataframe?

I am looking for something along these lines:

```py
# df is a dask.dataframe with a JSON blob in the `data` column

def process(row):
    json_data = json.loads(row.data)
    return Row(a=json_data["a"], b=json_data["b")

result = df.apply(
    process,
    axis=1,
).compute()

result
```

I see that the rows are themselves `pd.Series`, so I tried `process` returning a `Series` but I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

The [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply) suggests I can use the `meta` parameter in `apply`:

> meta: An empty pd.DataFrame or pd.Series that matches the dtypes and column names of the output ... [Inputs like] iterable of (name, dtype) can be provided (note that the order of the names should match the order of the columns)

However when I use an `iterable` of meta tuples, as suggested

```py
result = df.apply(
    process,
    axis=1,
    meta=[("a", "int")]
).compute()
```

it's expecting a `DataFrame` object and returns this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31364127/11390523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dask wrapper around a pandas function developed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512372/10693596):

```py
# see unutbu's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25512372/10693596
import json
def json_to_series(text):
    keys, values = zip(*[item for dct in json.loads(text) for item in dct.items()])
    return pd.Series(values, index=keys)


def process_chunk(df):
    _tmp = df['data'].apply(json_to_series)
    return pd.concat([df, _tmp], axis=1)

result = df.map_partitions(process_chunk).compute()
```