# Pandas – Extracting a phrase in a dict column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a specific text in one column that I want to extract, and wondering if I could extract a specific sequence from the rows in that column and add them to a new column.

From this:

```
|studios|
|-------|
|[{'mal_id': 14, 'name': 'Sunrise'}]|
|[{'mal_id': 34, 'name': 'Hal Film Maker'}]|
|[{'mal_id': 18, 'name': 'Toei Animation'}]|
|[]|
|[{'mal_id': 455, 'name': 'Palm Studio'}]|
```

To this:

```
|studios|
|-------|
|Sunrise|
|Hal Film Maker|
|Toei Animation|
|[]|
|Palm Studio|
```

Comment: Your 'studios' column is just a dict, presumably this came from JSON data.  You should use `read_json()` to convert the JSON into a proper dataframe

Comment: Will you please show the result of `print(type(df['studios'].iloc[0]))`? Thank you :)

Comment: Related: [Pandas expand json field across records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25511765/pandas-expand-json-field-across-records)

Comment: @richardec Here's the output: '<class 'str'>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str` to access indexes/keys from the lists/dicts of items in a column, and use a combination of `pipe` and `where` to fallback to the original values where the result from `.str` returns NaN:

```
df['studios'] = df['studios'].str[0].str['name'].pipe(lambda x: x.where(x.notna(), df['studios']))
```

Note: you *may* need to convert the items in `df['studio']` to actual objects, in case they're just strings that *look* like objects. To do that, run this before you run the above code:

```
import ast
df['studios'] = df['studios'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: OMG, thank so you much!!! It works now and you just saved me from having a mental breakdown!